# Can I optimize Ubuntu for touch integration?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

I recently installed a usb touch screen to my Toshiba Satellite. Can I optimize Ubuntu 13.10 for touch integration?

I have heard of the new Ubuntu Touch, seemingly only for phones, but I was curious as to whether this same idea is possible on a desktop or laptop. All my computers run Ubuntu (I have around twenty six, feww) so this would be a great help to set towards setting them each to their individual needs. I cannot program coding but I can run the terminal quite well if that helps any.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of ubuntu was not designed with touch in mind. For the future, the idea is to have a shell which scales to all the different devices (unity 8). This one is still a work in progress and it is at the moment used only on smartphones and tablet (soon in theory). This interface will probably reach the desktop in the following months or in the next year (no eta is available). At the moment you can only try the phone/tablet interface on the desktop if you want, but it is not very usable right now.

Comment: Thank you, that is extreamly helpful to know. I'll keep a look out for the latest version.